# When I open the activity,the app close automatically

Tags: kotlin, android-activity, gridview, crash, adapter

```
import android.content.Context

import android.content.Intent

import android.os.Bundle

import android.text.Editable

import android.text.TextWatcher

import android.view.View

import android.widget.Button

import android.widget.EditText

import android.widget.GridView

import android.widget.ImageView

import android.widget.Toast

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

import com.google.gson.Gson

import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

class Preservatifs : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var gridView: GridView

    private lateinit var adapter: ProductAdapter

    private val products = listOf(

        Product("Manix Intact", 6000, R.drawable.manix_intact),

        Product("SKYN", 6500, R.drawable.manix_skyn),

        Product("Extra pleasure", 6000, R.drawable.manix_extra_pleasure)

    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_preservatifs)

        gridView = findViewById(R.id.grid_preservatifs)

        adapter = ProductAdapter(this, products)

        gridView.adapter = adapter

        val searchEditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.searchview)

        searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

                if (s is CharSequence) {

                    adapter.filter.filter(s.toString())

                }

            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}

        })

        val doneButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.valider)

        doneButton.setOnClickListener {

            val selectedProducts = adapter.getSelectedProductsInfo()

            // Stocker les informations dans les préférences partagées

            val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

            val json = sharedPreferences.getString("selectedProducts", null)

            val selectionListType = object : TypeToken<List<Selection>>() {}.type

            val storedSelectionList = if (json != null) {

                Gson().fromJson<List<Selection>>(json, selectionListType)

            } else {

                mutableListOf()

            }

            val updatedSelectionList = mutableListOf<Selection>()

            updatedSelectionList.addAll(storedSelectionList)

            for (product in selectedProducts) {

                updatedSelectionList.add(Selection(product.name, product.price))

            }

            val updateJson = Gson().toJson(updatedSelectionList)

            val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()

            editor.putString("selectedProducts", updateJson)

            editor.apply()

            // Afficher un message à l'utilisateur

            Toast.makeText(this, "Votre course a été ajoutée au panier", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            doneButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

            val deuxiemeBouton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.allerPanier)

            deuxiemeBouton.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        }

        val deuxiemeBouton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.allerPanier)

        deuxiemeBouton.setOnClickListener {

            // Créer une Intent pour ouvrir l'activité Panier

            val intent = Intent(this, PanierTotal::class.java)

            startActivity(intent)

        }

        val retour = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.retour)

        retour.setOnClickListener {

            val intent = Intent(this, IntimePrincipale::class.java)

            startActivity(intent)

        }

    }

}

import android.content.Context

import android.view.LayoutInflater

import android.view.View

import android.view.ViewGroup

import android.widget.BaseAdapter

import android.widget.Filter

import android.widget.Filterable

import android.widget.ImageView

import android.widget.TextView

class ProductAdapter(private val context: Context, private val products: List<Product>) :

    BaseAdapter(), Filterable {

    private val selectedProducts = mutableListOf<Selection>()

    private val selectedProductInfo = mutableListOf<String>()

    private var filteredProducts = mutableListOf<Product>()

    init {

        filteredProducts = products.toMutableList()

    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {

        return filteredProducts.size

    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {

        return filteredProducts[position]

    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {

        return position.toLong()

    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

        val view = convertView ?: LayoutInflater.from(context)

            .inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false)

        val productImageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.product_image)

        val productNameView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.product_name)

        val productPriceView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.product_price)

        val product = filteredProducts[position]

        productImageView.setImageResource(product.image)

        productNameView.text = product.name

        productPriceView.text = product.price.toString()

        view.setOnClickListener {

            val selection = Selection(product.name, product.price)

            if (selectedProducts.contains(selection)) {

                selectedProducts.remove(selection)

                selectedProductInfo.remove("${product.name} ${product.price}")

                view.background = null

            } else {

                selectedProducts.add(selection)

                selectedProductInfo.add("${product.name} ${product.price}")

                view.setBackgroundColor(

                    ContextCompat.getColor(

                        context,

                        android.R.color.holo_green_light

                    )

                )

            }

        }

        return view

    }

    fun getSelectedProductsInfo(): List<Selection> {

        return selectedProducts

    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {

        return object : Filter() {

            override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {

                val results = FilterResults()

                filteredProducts = if (constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty()) {

                    products.toMutableList()

                } else {

                    products.filter {

                        it.name.contains(constraint.toString(), ignoreCase = true)

                    }.toMutableList()

                }

                results.count = filteredProducts.size

                results.values = filteredProducts

                return results

            }

            override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {

                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {

                    filteredProducts = results.values as MutableList<Product>

                    notifyDataSetChanged()

                } else {

                    notifyDataSetInvalidated()

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you properly format your code block please. And, add more context. We have no idea what is the error you are experiencing.

Comment: If your app closes when you open it, it's crashing. Check the logs for an error message and stack trace (the lines below explaining what led up to the crash), and add those to your question in a code block if you need help working out what's happening